# Efficiency of passing a combined string as an argument

Tags: c++, performance, stl

I want to call a function with an argument, which is a constructed string. For example:

```
std::string str = "data";
// ...
debug("we have " + str + " and it's good");
```

[ideone link](http://ideone.com/hTO3g7).

As far as I know, it creates a string in the first concatenation, and then creates a new one in the second concatenation, which means two inevitable allocations.

Is the following code more performant?

```
std::string str = "data";
// ...
debug(std::string("we have ") += str += " and it's good");
```

Or is the first code being optimized by the compiler to something similar?

Comment: it depends a lot by the compiler you are using and the way `debug` is written, there is no absolute answer

Comment: "performant" compared to what? - I can't think of an alternative that is reasonable.

Comment: The first one is more optimized. You don't need to hep the compiler.

Comment: You might use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/), but I can't imagine it being worth it.

Comment: @Paul I put up this quite naive sample http://ideone.com/n8WY3m, it shows what you're saying but I have no idea if it's flawed

Comment: I wouldn't expect the compiler to optimise either of them. And the latter is just more ugly. You're going to have to _measure_ it though.

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz looks like I was right about my assumption that the second example is a better option. Thanks. Still, it would be nice to get a more confident answer, with info about compiler guarantees vs implementation details.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit doesn't the example of Alejandro Díaz contradict your comment? In the second example only one object is created, and if it happened to reserve enough allocated bytes, no reallocation or copying will take place. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Paul: Alejandro's example is not the same as yours.